# Query Precision and Recall vs Sort

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a catalog of products and I'm facing some problems when I try to sort the results by other criteria than by relevance.

Today I can sort the results in order: most recent and most rated.

My query has the characteristic of having the most accurate results on the first page of results and the other pages are the result of recall.

When I try to order the results by the "most rated" criteria, the results on the first page are meaningless with the search term but the document is returned because a word of the search term exists in the document.

Index Data:

```
POST idx_test/_bulk
{"index": {}}
{"name": "course english advance", "rating": 2 }
{"index": {}}
{"name": "course english mediujm", "rating": 4 }
{"index": {}}
{"name": "english by teacher", "rating": 2 }
{"index": {}}
{"name": "course makeup", "rating": 5 }
{"index": {}}
{"name": "course craftwork ", "rating": 2 }
```

Search for: english course

```
GET idx_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "course english"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Results:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "YQqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.7777306,
        "_source": {
          "name": "course english advance",
          "rating": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "YgqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.7777306,
        "_source": {
          "name": "course english mediujm",
          "rating": 4
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "YwqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.5070823,
        "_source": {
          "name": "english by teacher",
          "rating": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "ZAqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.3176721,
        "_source": {
          "name": "course makeup",
          "rating": 5
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "ZQqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.3176721,
        "_source": {
          "name": "course craftwork ",
          "rating": 2
        }
      }
    ]
```

If I order by the best rating, the result is:

```
GET idx_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "course english"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "rating": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Results:

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "ZAqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.3176721,
        "_source": {
          "name": "course makeup",
          "rating": 5
        },
        "sort": [
          5,
          0.3176721
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "YgqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.7777306,
        "_source": {
          "name": "course english mediujm",
          "rating": 4
        },
        "sort": [
          4,
          0.7777306
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "YQqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.7777306,
        "_source": {
          "name": "course english advance",
          "rating": 2
        },
        "sort": [
          2,
          0.7777306
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "YwqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.5070823,
        "_source": {
          "name": "english by teacher",
          "rating": 2
        },
        "sort": [
          2,
          0.5070823
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index": "idx_test",
        "_id": "ZQqH8YkBOnuUjQMmwaIc",
        "_score": 0.3176721,
        "_source": {
          "name": "course craftwork ",
          "rating": 2
        },
        "sort": [
          2,
          0.3176721
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Does anyone have any guidance to get the ordering only in the documents that make sense with the search term?

I have already tried to have a query that is just precise but I need to retrieve documents that may be relevant and with that the ordering fails in many searches.

Comment: Please share the example document and the current query. Also, you can check this article to understand what you need: https://medium.com/quantyca/reviving-an-e-commerce-search-engine-using-elasticsearch-e540751c6d99

Comment: Thanks for sharing the sample data and the query. Just to clarify Is the expected output like the following order?
          **"name": "course english mediujm",
          "name": "course english advance",
          "name": "course makeup",
          "name": "english by teacher",
          "name": "course craftwork ",**

Comment: Yes, the expectation would be to have the highest rating but in relation to the research context. It would be 1- course english mediujm, 2- course english advance, 3- english by teacher, 4- course makeup 5-course craftwork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) with `field_value_factor` can help you to achieve what you want.

```
GET idx_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "name": "course english"
        }
      },
      "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "rating",
        "factor": 0.1,
        "modifier": "none"
      },
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think your suggestion opened my mind to other strategies, thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome Rabbit, thanks for your feedback and question!